# Find the Number of possible topological sort

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, relations, order-theory

### Question

> Find the Number of possible  topological sort of following diagram defined on relation $\preceq$ (not interested in what this relation is)
> [image: here]

### My Answer

I am getting possible Topological sort

$T1 \preceq T4 \preceq T5 $

$T1 \preceq T2 \preceq T3 \preceq T5 $

$T1 \preceq T3 \preceq T5 $

Am i right or missing anything?

Thanks!

Comment: A topological sort is a total order, of all five elements.  None of the three answers presented are total orders.  There are just two answers.

Comment: @vadim123 it would be better if you please give some more hint to solve this

Comment: In other words, in how many ways can the partial order specified in the picture (directed graph) be extended to a total order?  See [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) in Wikipedia, a phrase that sometimes is used to refer to an algorithm to find such a total order.

Comment: A similar Question was [Find all possible topological-sortings of graph G](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489773/find-all-possible-topological-sortings-of-graph-g).  The answers there give some good pointers on organizing the search visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every total order must include all the relationships in the graph, plus additional ones to make it into a total order.  Note that $T_1$ must come first: $T_1$ must come before $T_2, T_3, T_4$, and $T_3$ must come before $T_5$.  Note also that $T_2$ must come second, since it must come before $T_3, T_4, T_5$.  Finally, note that $T_5$ must come last, since both $T_3$ and $T_4$ must come before $T_5$.  Hence the only answers are

$$T_1 < T_2 < T_3 < T_4 < T_5$$

and

$$T_1 < T_2 < T_4 < T_3 < T_5$$